# OPTIONS request returns "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header" error during ajax POST to a different domain

Tags: ajax, angularjs, post, cors

I'm struggling with CORS issue. I make a request from js to a different domain, the method allows cross domain request and all works fine with **GET** but not with **POST** request. Looks like **OPTIONS** method is called before the **POST** and return standard error

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.`

`return Response.ok().entity(c).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
     .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS")
     .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, x-xsrf-token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Expires, Last-Modified, Cache-Control").build();`

On the client side I use angularjs

`$http.post(url, data).success(...)`

But also tried with

`$.ajax({type:'POST',
         headers: {
             'Accept': 'application/json',
             'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         }...})`

the same result. what else can I do to fix **POST** request?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code to your Angular JS application config file

$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;

delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];